# Express is not rendering the page in the browser if called from a client-side JS function via XHR

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

In order to pre-process some data from the browser, i'm triggering Express from the browser via a JS XHR call. The problem is that the browser is apparently not showing the page rendered by Node/Express on the server

Not a matter of file paths, views etc. Other EJS templates get rendered perfectly when invoked by clicking on a  object in the browser

HTML code:

```
<button type='button' class='button' onclick='sendData()'>Action</button>

<script language='javascript'>
    function sendData() {
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        const filename = document.getElementById('fileselect').files[0]; 
        // reads the file and pass it to the server as a string
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsText(filename);
        reader.onload = function() {
            var fileContent = reader.result;
            var obj = 'file=' + fileContent;
            obj = encodeURI(obj);
            http.addEventListener('load', function (event) {
                //alert('Yeah! Data sent and response loaded.');
            });

            // Define what happens in case of error
            http.addEventListener('error', function (event) {
                alert('Oops! Something went wrong.');
            });

            http.open('POST', '/action', true);

    http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    http.send(obj);
</script>
```

NODE:

```
app.post('/action', function(req, res){
//console.log(req.body);
const file = req.body.file;
// process the data
...
res.render("page.ejs");
```

Comment: To be more accurate, with reference to the code, the page.ejs does NOT get rendered in the browser in response

Comment: `language='javascript'` — Why are you writing HTML 3.2 in 2019?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the page.ejs does NOT get rendered in the browser in response

You've done nothing to render it there.

The point of Ajax is that you are making an HTTP request from and handling the response with *JavaScript*.

You are not navigating the browser to a new page.

If you want to do something with the response (like display it in the page) then you need to do that here:

> ```
>         http.addEventListener('load', function (event) {
>             //alert('Yeah! Data sent and response loaded.');
>         });
> ```

The data will be in `this.responseText`.

However, if you want that … then you should probably be using a regular form submission and not using Ajax at all.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Quentin. Supposing I'm returning to JS the rendered page, how can I actually display it on the browser? Furthermore, to your comment, I'm not using a regular form submission as, AFAIK, that supports PHP only (if I'm not mistaken). Any suggestion here? Thanks! @Quentin

Comment: "how can I actually display it on the browser" — https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction

Comment: "I'm not using a regular form submission as, AFAIK, that supports PHP only (if I'm not mistaken)." — You're mistaken. I can't think of any programming language which can't handle a regular form submission when used for server-side programming.

Comment: Got it, works perfectly Quentin => thanks a lot! This is the code:     http.addEventListener('load', function (event) {
    document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = this.responseText;
});